# Methods to restrict iframe src page to be used in their AMP pages only?

Tags: amp-html

How to restrict iframe src page to be used in their AMP pages only?

Any thoughts on the below two options?

1. Using X-Frame-Options and allow their domain and .ampproject.org might be one solutions but seems like ALLOW-FROM option is not compatible to most of the mobile browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=X-Frame-Options
2. Using CSP frame-ancestors seems to be a better solutions in terms of supported browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Comment: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/caches.json

Answer (score 0):

While both provide the best coverage, please note that there are other AMP caches, not only Google's, so it is hard to know all domains.

You could also use location.ancestorOrigins in JavaScript. This works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.